# Webservice call not working on 3G on Android 4.1.2 Devices

Tags: android, web-services, 3g

I developed an `application` which calls a `webservice` through `Wi-Fi` and if `Wi-Fi` is not availabel then it switches to `3G`.

The problem is , `webservice` call is working on `Wi-Fi` but `not working` on `3G` on Android 4.1.2 Devices.

I browsed the `webservice` on browser on `3G` , it is browsing fine.

I need help in this.

**Code of Network Rechability**

```
android.net.ConnectivityManager conMgr =  (android.net.ConnectivityManager)General.MainContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);          

result = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting();
```

Comment: Can you post the code used for checking the network rechability

Comment: Switching is automatic , and it is working fine on other devices

Comment: what is the error post your logcat

Comment: So, are you saying your code works on devices that *aren't* running 4.1.2?

Comment: I can't access the logcat for some reason. But the exception is SocketTimeoutException. Socket is closing

Comment: Yes , it is running on all the devices except the devices running 4.1.2